# Javascript: How to use a regular expression in a loop

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have a question. I want to build a regular expression in java script within a loop. I have the string "hi!whats.up" and I want to select in the loop each substring ("hi!","whats","up"), with a regular expression.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please consider sharing some code that you've tried already

Comment: @Tester thx for your answer. I have no code yet and don't want have the whole code from anybody. I just want to understand the regular expression of this example. I know that I can use " [.].* " But this just takes the substring ".up". And I want to have all three pieces in the regex.

Comment: Do you want to include the `!` with the preceding word but not other special characters?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) together with a regular expression for symbols.

Something like

```
"hi!whats.up".split(/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/)
    .forEach(function (word) {
        console.log(word);
})
```

Comment: thank you. So is "word" my variable? Like var String word="hi!whats.up" ?

Comment: when I compile that I get an error at the (/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/)

Comment: No, that's just for logging. The hardcoded "hi!whats.up" is what's being split

Answer (score 1):

```
let [a, b, c] = 'hi!whats.up'.split (/[^\w]+/)
```